# Print a triangle in C

Tags: c

I want to develop a program which prints a triangle shown below:

```
     1
    A B 
   1 2 3
  A B C D
```

Using a for loop in C.
Any idea how come up with program?

Comment: People won't provide you with code here. I also don't think that you **want** to program this, you will probably **have** to do this. What have you got so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: maybe you will find that interesting : http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Try to do it your self.... Let me give you a hint one for loop can be used to increase number of character in each line... one is same can be used too decrease the space in each line... odd and even counter to decide ABC or 123...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
f(int n)
{
  int i , j ;
  for( i = 1 ; i <= n ; i ++ )
  { 
    j = 1 ;
    while( j <= (n-i) ) { printf(" "); j++ ;}
    j = 0 ;
    while( j <= i )
    {
      if( i % 2 != 0 )
        printf("%d ", j );
      else
        printf("%c ", j + 'A' );
      printf("\n"); 
      j ++ ;
    }
  }
}
```

Now if someone can do it in time < O(n2) That is welcome :)

Comment: It probably won't be possible in `<O(n^2)` since you have to print `O(n^2)` characters to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print `n` lines in total:

- the first line consists of 1 char and `n-1` spaces in front of it
- the second line consists of 3 chars and `n-2` spaces in front of them
- the second line consists of 5 chars and `n-3` spaces in front of them
- the `i`-th line consists of `___` chars and `___` spaces in front of them (please fill in missing fields

How to determine what to print:

- the first line consists of numbers
- the second line consists of alphabetical chars
- the third line consists of numbers
- the fourth line consists of alphabetical chars

Please formulate a rule that determines which lines contain which signs:

```
_______________________________________________________________________________

_______________________________________________________________________________
```

You can print numbers with: `printf("%d", number)`. You can print chars with `printf("%c",char)`.

You can do addition on characters as well: `'A' + 2` yields `'C'`.

Now it should be no real problem to program the program you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * pie = "     1\n    A B\n   1 2 3\n  A B C D\n";
for (i=0;i<1;i++) printf("%s", pie);
```